# How to retain original range when updating data validation rule with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a google apps script that updates an existing data validation rule to toggle the "Show dropdown list in cell" option.  I have it mostly working, it does change the "Show dropdown list in cell" option, however it is not retaining the original criteria range, which is on a different sheet.  It appears to be changing the range to use the sheet the validation rule was from instead of the other sheet. The original data validation requires a value in the range `Sheet2!A2:A`, but when I run the below script, it changes to require a value in the range `Base!A2:A` instead.

```
function turnOffDropDown()  {
    var baseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base");
    var templateRange = baseSheet.getRange("B2");
    var rule = templateRange.getDataValidation();
    var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
    var args = rule.getCriteriaValues();
    args[1] = false;
    var newRule = rule.copy().withCriteria(criteria, args).build();
    templateRange.setDataValidation(newRule);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong that it isn't retaining the original range, is there a way to specify the range I want on Sheet2, or is there a different way to update the "Show dropdown list in cell" option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug and should probably be reported [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support). I've tried your approach as well as explicitly defining the range, but it consistently replaces the criteria *sheet* with the sheet in which the validation is being applied, while maintaining the specified cells. (E.g., the validation is being applied to `Worksheet!C1`, so `CriteriaValues!A1:10` becomes `Worksheet!A1:10`.)

As a workaround, given that you're likely not changing the criteria type, you can try creating a new validation instead using [`requireValueInRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinrangerange-showdropdown). I've modified your code to create a "Toggle Dropdown" option. This does maintain the correct range.

```
function toggleDropDown()  {
  var baseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base");
  var templateRange = baseSheet.getRange("B1");
  var rule = templateRange.getDataValidation();
  var args = rule.getCriteriaValues();
  rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(args[0], !args[1]).build();
  templateRange.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```